# CakePHP ACL - On the fly permission management?

Tags: cakephp, acl

Greetings!

im pretty new to cakePHP and just starting to use the ACL feature.
From the outside it looks quite ok, but when i started using it.. well its not that ok anymore :)

Im working on an application with an administration backend in which i need to be able to change group permissions on the fly. I tortured google for quite a while now and i couldnt find any good example on how to implement that. I found tons of posts about the command line tool, but i'd like not to use that out of my application.

Does anyone know a way to implement this or a decent tutorial/howto which addresses that?

Comment: Group permission on the filesystem, or group permissions from within the web app?

Comment: Have you read through this? http://book.cakephp.org/view/469/Creating-Access-Request-Objects-AROs-and-Access-Co

Comment: @Trevis Leleu: Group permissions from within the webapp.
@deceze: I got it to do that, but i cant get the ACL (so the permissions) to work from within the app. ACO's are created just fine...

Comment: you're not trying to use it for record-level locking, are you?  Cuz it doesn't do that.  It really is for heirarchical permissions to the combination of controller/action, based on user/group permissions.  I think there are other components in the bakery that might help, but I've never found a great record locking mechanism in Cake.  Anyone?

Comment: @Travis Leleu no i dont need that for my current app, but actually when i think about it you're right. The only easy way i can think of is a function in your model which executes a custom query on the supplied entry and creates a lock on it (col which holds either 0 or 1). Then add another function which is executed before you save a record which checks if the field is set to 1 for that record. But i cant think of any built in solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried them but I have heard of an ACL management plugin by Jeff Loiselles aka Phishy and I also here that Croogo, one of the CakePHP CMS's by fahad19 has ACL management feature, may be you could extract it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Authake](https://github.com/nchankov/authake). Read the Wiki for installation instructions. It has a decent GUI and works with 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this plugin ? It has a GUI to manage the users/roles permissions and can fill the ACL database tables for you: http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl

A demo is also available here: http://demo.alaxos.ch/admin/acl/aros/index

Comment: Oups, I didn't notice this thread was so old. So why did it just appear in my RSS feed ?